# WO and PCT patents do they have different jurisdictions?

Tags: pct, expired, valid, wo

WO and PCT patents do they have different jurisdictions ?
If the WO patent has expired, can the PCT patent still be valid?
If the PTC patent has expired, can the WO patent still be valid?
WO 2005006842 A3 and PCT/CA2004/001083 are patents for the same invention,if the one is still valid and the other one has expired can there still be a valid patent?

Answer (score 2):

"WO" is the two letter country code for PCT applications. As for patents in other territories, an application is first given an application number and then a separate publication number.  In fact, these two numbers you mention relate to the same application (application number PCT/CA2004/001083 was published as WO 2005/006842).

An International Patent Application (PCT) itself "expires" 30 months from the earliest priority date (23 July 2003 in this case) when the International Phase ends.  After that, the application proceeds in each individual country/territory in National Phases as selected by the applicant.

The public database espacenet shows national application numbers in Europe, US, Australia, Japan, Canada and China (http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=EP&NR=1646275A2&KC=A2&FT=D&ND=4&date=20060419&DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP).  The current status will depend on what happened in each individual territory.